# 'RCTAppDelegate.h' file not found in Xcode

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, build

I've recently bought a react native template and I'm since then struggling to start it, I've tried every possible solutions about this issue but xcode keeps failing the build and give me this error. in vs code the error might change depending of the solution I'm trying, the last one beeing

The following build commands failed:

```
        CompileC /Users/sashakharoubi/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Cookie-boiyvxbmpsexaldhanwqctldubxz/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Cookie.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cookie.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/AppDelegate.o /Users/sashakharoubi/Downloads/Cookie/CookieReact/ios/Cookie/AppDelegate.mm normal x86_64 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'Cookie' from project 'Cookie')
(1 failure)
```

```
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : RCTAppDelegate

@end
```

I'd really appreciate some help, its beens days and not finding what's wrong. I'm using a 2018 macbook pro intel.

Thanks for the help

I've tried reinstalling the pods, reinstall the pods with the arm64 x86, tried to add some headers to the PodFile before the initialization lines, tried to remove and reinstall the node modules, my file has no space or special characters nether the root file.